# What is actually "type-bound subroutine" in Fortran and related?

Tags: oop, fortran

I am very new to Fortran language and I just picked it up for a month. (I use C/C++ more often)
I have a few questions:

1. What is the "type-bound subroutine"? What I understand is that the subroutine can only be called by a certain instance with a certain type.
   (http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Object-oriented+programming). None of the book I read actually provide a good definition of this in fact, quite surprising.
2. If derived type can also have subroutines, what is the difference between putting them inside the derived type and outside (normal ones in modules)?
3. Following the link above, "Note that we have changed the dummy parameters from type(Circle) to class(Circle). We can then call the class functions in an object-oriented fashion as a = c%area and call c%print, where the type is passed to the first argument of the functions circle_area and circle_print automatically." To me, this is like the "this pointer" in C++ (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_this_pointer.htm). So if we place the subroutine inside the derived type, I think the type will be no longer necessary when designing a subroutine?

Thanks, I hope I have explained clearly enough.

Comment: *"    So if we place the subroutine inside the derived type, I think the type will be no longer necessary when designing a subroutine?"* I do not understsnd what do you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type bound procedures offer a different way of referencing a procedure - the procedure is referenced through an object of derived type via a binding.  Beyond a difference in syntax, the reference through an object of derived type allows the specific procedure to be referenced to be determined at runtime based on the dynamic type of the object. This is similar in C++ to a reference to a virtual member function through a pointer or reference to an object.  An extension of a derived type with a binding may override the procedure that the binding references.

Unlike C++, a procedure in Fortran may be bound to one or more derived types - you do not put a procedure inside a derived type.  A procedure that happens to be type bound may also be referenced directly without type bound syntax, just like it would be in Fortran 95.

When a procedure is bound to a type, the binding may nominate a passed argument. If there is a passed argument and the procedure is referenced using type bound syntax, the passed argument is associated with the object that the procedure was referenced through.  This is roughly the equivalent of the implicit *this* pointer in C++, but in Fortran the argument is explicitly passed and named.

An argument that is a passed argument in a procedure that is type bound must be polymorphic - declared with CLASS rather than TYPE - to allow for the dynamic type of the passed argument to be an extenddion of the declared type of the argument.

Comment: It would be great you can list a few examples. The answer is very helpful already.